# I want to check about the pushed name in the object if its found in the array it won't be re-pushed but it pushed anyway

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is html code

```html
<body>
    <section>

        <h1>client profile informations</h1>
        <div class="madaro" v-on:click.right.prevent>
            <div>
                <input v-model="newstu" type="text">
                <input v-model="newgpa" type="number" @keyup.enter="addio">
                <button @click="addio" > submit</button>
            </div>
            <h1 v-for="grade in grades">
                Student {{grade.name}} has final grade {{grade.gpa}}
            </h1>
        </div>
    </section>
```

the new name is pushed every time whatever the condition

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <script> 
**the array**

   grades:[
            {
                name:'pac',
                gpa:'4'
            },
            {
                name:'ray',
                gpa:1.2
            },
            {
                name:'ssy',
                gpa:4.4
            },
            {
                name:'snri',
                gpa:3.5
            },
            {
                name:'safa',
                gpa:1.7
            },
            {
                name:'mohammed',
                gpa:5
            },
            {
                name:'mammt',
                gpa:4.1
            }
        ],
        newgpa:'',
        newstu:''
    },

*the function*

    methods:{
        addio(){
        
        if (this.grades.name === this.newstu) {
            console.log('hyhy');
        } else {
        return this.grades.push({name:this.newstu , gpa:this.newgpa});    
        }

**empty the input field**

        this.newstu =''
        this.newgpa=''
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addio()` isn't actually checking whether the entry already exists in `this.grades[]`. It only compares `newstu` (the newly entered student name) to `this.grades.name`, which doesn't exist because `this.grades` is an `Array`.

One solution is to use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search `this.grades[]` for a matching entry. Every callback to `find()` receives an array entry, which can be used to compare the entry's `name` property against `this.newstu`. If the entry is not found, `find()` returns `undefined`, so you can use the call in an `if`-statement:

```js
if (this.grades.find(grade => grade.name === this.newstu)) {
  // already exists...ignore

} else {
  // new entry
  this.grades.push({ name: this.newstu, gpa: this.newgpa })
}
```